# Can't change font-weight - Select Component Antd

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

I'm starting in programming and I'm creating a select component with ant-design, but I can't change the font-weight of ant-design. The component accepts all the properties I pass, except the font-weight. I would like the font-weight to take the "Data de Início". Any solution? Thanks

```
export function CustomSelect({ onChange, options, value }) {
  return (
    <div className={cx('tw-rounded tw-flex tw-items-center tw-justify-center tw-text-xs tw-text-hoki', styles.ordenarDiv)}>
      <span className={cx('tw-ml-8 tw-font-semibold', styles.ordenarSpan)}>Ordenar por:</span>
      <Select
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
        bordered={false}
        dropdownClassName={styles.dropDown}
        className={cx('tw-rounded', styles.select)}
        dropdownMatchSelectWidth={false}>
        {options.map((item) => {
          const classOption = item.id === value ? styles.optionSelected : styles.options
          return (
            <Option key={item.id} value={item.id} className={classOption}>
              {item.value}
            </Option>
          )
        })}
      </Select>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
.select {
    background: transparent;
    color: #64869f;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700px;
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxAgD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To change font-weight in Select field you can override ant style:

```
.ant-select-selection-item {
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

To change font-weight in Option fields you can override:

```
.ant-select-item-option-content {
    font-weight: 900;
}
```